# Visual Studio Code no reconoce funciones de php que estoy trabajando con wordpress me dice que la función no está definida

Tags: php, funciones

[image: Me subraya el llamado de wp que hace referencia a wordpress]

Hola estoy aprendiendo a utlizar temas en wordpress con php, y al intentar en Visual Studio Code llamar una funcion de wp_head  dentro del HTML5, no la reconoce, alguien que me pueda ayudar, ya he intentado con instalar la extensión PHP Intelephense y verificar que esté en true el php.suggest.basic  pero aún no la reconoce

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890854/vs-code-highlighted-all-my-wordpress-function-name

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto, WordPress está desactivado en PHP Intelephense, por ello no te reconoce sus funciones.

1. Ubica la extensión y accede a sus ajustes:

[image: Extensión PHP Intelephense]

2. Navega hasta abajo en "Stubs" y añade "wordpress". Finalmente, click en "OK". Reinicia de preferencia.

[image: Stubs en PHP Intelephense]

[image: wordpress en PHP Intelephense]